# Javascript positioning issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm on a plugin that takes the placeholder's value of an input or textarea, and creates a div overlaying this input that disappears on click...
I position this div with javascript retreiving his sibling input's or textarea's position().

Trying to make the plugin bulletproof i change the inputs widths and heights every 5 seconds,
and normally the div.placeholder should position itself but some bugs appears.

I made a fiddle here > http://goo.gl/Ytmxm

Can someone help with this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is perfect.

The problem you see is because the position you get from `offset()` is the old one. I have modified the fiddle to trigger `inputChange` 1ms after you change the dimensions and it works.
http://jsfiddle.net/PvLnH/1/

Look out at refreshes sometimes it plays tricks.

Here is the solution I describe in my comment:
http://jsfiddle.net/PvLnH/3/

Comment: On a side note, I would like to suggest another solution: wrap the input in a container, have it position relatively without padding or dimensions so it exactly fits the input. Then put your placeholder in that wrapper with position absolute, top,bottom,left,right at 0px will make it cover the hole thing.

This way it will resize by itself if the input changes size. No need to refresh it in JavaScript :)

Comment: Thank you Sir !
I updated the fiddle again integrating the timeout in the plugin.

Works like a charm :)

Comment: But I cannot wrap the input because the plugin is meant to be used on a project i can't modify... And this way i'm sure that it will work on a variety of markups...

Comment: You are right the markup addition might cause some problems but most of the time it will not change anything as long as the CSS rules is enforced inline by the plugin.